# Can't write to temp folder in Windows 7 using ofstream

Tags: c++, windows, qt

As I'm using Qt, I use the Qt-way to get Windows Temp Folder. This works, but then it appears I can't write to this folder.

Here is the code :

```
   const QStringList defaultFolders = QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::TempLocation);
   const QString tempFolder = defaultFolders.first();
   const QString fileName = tempFolder + "/testFile.txt";

   ofstream file(fileName.toLocal8Bit(), fstream::out);
   const bool ok = file.is_open();

   const QString msg = ok ? "Success" : "Failure";
   QMessageBox::warning(this, fileName, msg);
```

**What I tried so far**

- Using hard-coded path with "\\" instead of "/"
- Using .toStdString().c_str() instead of ".toLocal8bit()

**Notes**

- There is an accentuated character in the path.
- The Windows user is an administrator
- I can manually create/delete files in the temp folder, but the compiled application cannot.
- I am running Windows 7 in a virtual machine
- **It works fine if I use old C functions (fopen/fwrite/fclose)**

Someone has an idea of what is going wrong?

Comment: Perhaps using `toStdWString()` instead of `toLocal8Bit()` would work better? `std::filesystem::path filePath(fileName.toStdWString()); std::ofstream file(filePath);` Haven't tried it myself though.

Comment: Temp path on your machine might contain non-English characters. `toLocal8Bit()` might not work in this case.  If you are not familiar with character encoding, just use QFile and  QTextStream instead of std library.

Comment: @CongMa You're right, there are non-english characters in the path. I already specified this in the Notes section of my question.
Using QFile/QTextStream would probably resolve my issue but that was not the point of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps using `toStdWString()` instead of `toLocal8Bit()` would work better?

```
std::filesystem::path filePath(fileName.toStdWString());
std::ofstream file(filePath);
```